# What series of AS/400 is the 9406 F2?

Tags: ibm, identify-this-computer, as400

I am considering the acquisition of an old IBM AS/400 midrange computer. The provider has stated the model is "9406 F2".

I have dived into the AS/400 information provided by IBM in their own websites to no avail. My first thought was to check the `Fxx` family, but model designations in that line start at `F35`.

Another candidate I checked was the `6xx` line but I have not much information to confirm if it belongs to it. After some time searching in content from other sources, I found a single unit of `9406 F2` being currently sold at ebay (see [here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/255806091071)). From what I saw at the listing, this `F2` complies with the following:

- Is an AS/400e system, prior to e-server and i-series.
- Is a rather big system with about 68+ cm wide, 83+ cm long and 1+ m tall.
- Primary color is black with secondary being blue (I found some other IBM computers having alternatively red decorations instead or blue, or none at all).

The information relative to the system was extracted from the listing and at the time of asking I have no confirmation about it. I need more precise information about the system to study the viability of the operation.

For this reason I would like to ask this community if someone knows/has worked with this system and could help me to properly identify it.

Comment: 9406 seems to be an IBM code for all AS/400 systems. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AS/400#System_models) tells me that there was an F02 released in 1993. That seems to have used the IMP hardware, inherited from the System/38.

Comment: @John Dallman Yes, I reached that same conclusion, then found theebay listing and ditched it. It is true that I found that IBM reused references across all the AS family - not just the 9406; but had it been IMP thin it would have been before the rebranding, therefore shouldn't it be cream-colored instead of black?

Comment: Be sure to get software and licenses.

Answer (score 8):

A search of IBM's rather voluminous redbook and redpaper resources shows no F2 model of the 9406 - these start at F35, as you state.

There's only a 940***2*** F02 model as described in the `AS/400 CISC System Builder V1R2-V3R6` redpaper `REDP-0042`. That has a rather comprehensive overview of AS/400 hardware and options, from introduction up to products announced as of mid-1995.

It was separated from the System Builder document, to keep size down, when the May 2000 edition of the AS/400e one was produced.

From cursory search, the [IBM RedBook](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/) site has only the AS/400***e*** variant but there's a copy of the CISC one [here](http://ps-2.kev009.com/as400/manuals/redp0042.pdf), at least at the time this answer was posted.

---

Based on the link you've now added (see extracted images below), that *really* looks like a 7xx we had floating around at IBM Software Labs when I worked there a decade or so ago (we used it for developing/testing one of the Tivoli z/OS products which gathered information from various mini- and micro-computer systems, as well as all the relevant mainframe hardware and software as well).

It appears to have the distinctive four-section tower body with the PSU/UPS in the bottom right (looking from the back) and feeding up to both the section above and to the left. You can see the similarity in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1ZP7-IJsWY) (at about 4:10 in).

[image: Front of machine]
[image: Rear of machine]

However, given the rather large number of ways you could *get* to a 7xx configuration (new, or a wide range of upgrade paths), it wouldn't surprise me in the least if this was a configuration that came from a earlier CISC model. If that were the case, the face-plate on the back of the tower is probably irrelevant to the tower's content.

I think if you wish to ascertain what you're actually getting for your money, you'll need to get pictures of all the hardware *inside* the tower, rather than relying on a possibly dubious face-plate.

Comment: Sorry for the effort, but I'm 100% positive the reference is correct. It may be wrong to add links, but I'm sharing the ebay listing I found - the only other reference to this model I've found. It is a bit blurry but the reference can still be read in the last picture.

Comment: Link to the listing, please check it (https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/255806091071?hash=item3b8f3b2f3f:g:pYwAAOSwC7Vhwh5j&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoHq%2FNahfphpGAkhd7RvYHyLfjw%2BTO78noWZ26aZqlRhJQ3jYzTERFraMkhblsN6atvi6JUgu4O43dZTYcXFSUMBcFq9ab39Dz%2BFySVI2F6aBgoH%2F16bV02n5LlEh1FGYSOydQD%2BQu1QW5IH8rr0L0OyJ5DQCun%2BuTERxwLlwPHWgI4uqfNw1iT4Wb%2F3SLLkg6PTXcCc%2BRhgdEI2aCklD0OM%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR-rrod2rYQ)

Comment: It has the likings of a 520/620/720 ?

Comment: About the "F30"... it was a typo. I should have said "about 30" or "F35" (now corrected to the latter)

Comment: Nevertheless, I am to examine the unit in about two weeks prior to finally decide if the operation is viable. I may be able to add more information then.

Comment: @Borg, hopefully the system will have a full history, *including* how it got to the 7xx state (if indeed it *is* a 7xx). That may help with figuring out the bizarre name-plate `9406 F2` tag (see my latest update to the answer).

Comment: @BorgDrone Where does it say F2?  The images don't seem very clear.  I worked with the AS/400 since before its launch (I was invited to a preview).  I don't recall any F2.  The early models were one letter and two digits.

Comment: @badjohn In the ebay listing, in the last picture (the 4th). Type is shownt at the black label, as well the electrical specs.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thank you. The upgrade path makes sense, it may be a conversion. I'd like to accept the answer, but until I can confirm the unit conversion hypothesis I shouldn't. Would you mind to wait some days?

Comment: @BorgDrone Thanks.  Now I see it.  That is surprising.  I have a very faint memory.  I think that the F2 might signify something other than the model number.  I need to do some research.

Comment: @BorgDrone: that's entirely fine, I may be totally wrong anyway, depending on what turns up from badjohn's research :-)